# Is there a way to hook into a Kubernetes Ingress Resource change event?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm creating a minimal custom ingress controller in dotnet core. I can access the k8s ingress resources by querying the api server, but polling doesn't seem like a good solution to update ingress rules since in my use case they aren't changed that often but if they change, the changes should be applied right away.

Is there a way to receive notifications on ingress resource changes? Like registering a webhook or something along the lines? Or is polling the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What dotnet core library are you using? There is a `Watch` on every resource in the golang client (e.g. [ingress](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/extensions/v1beta1#IngressInterface)). You can find our more about this under "Setup a Watch" section in [this article](https://medium.com/programming-kubernetes/building-stuff-with-the-kubernetes-api-part-4-using-go-b1d0e3c1c899)

It looks like there is a [Watch example in the kubernetes-client/csharp](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/master/examples/watch/Program.cs) as well.

Comment: yes, i guess watch is the way to go, if i understand it correctly it uses long polling. for reverse proxying i use https://github.com/damianh/ProxyKit with a few customizations. for kubernetes i currently don't use a library but plain rest api calls. didn't even realize there was one for dotnet, thanks for pointing it out.